# Что это за конструкция описания функции?

Tags: javascript, функции, синтаксис

В уроке по `js` встретил такое объявление функции:

```
// update dathoffset function

const updateDathOffset = () => {

};
```

Объясните, пожалуйста, что это за синтаксис, и можно ли его заменить чем-то типа:

```
const updateDathOffset = function (){

}
```

Как я понял в первом примере кода мы записываем в константу результат работы безымянной функции.

Comment: «мы записываем в константу результат работы безымянной функции» — не результат, а собственно саму эту функцию, которую потом можно вызывать как `updateDathOffset()`

Comment: @andreymal а почему тогда просто не описать функцию как function updateDathOffset(){}

Comment: А это уже у автора кода лучше спросить

Comment: @Konstantin_SH почитайте про `function expression` и `function declaration`. https://learn.javascript.ru/function-expressions